# Nowpayments API : POST Authentication C# | Error 400 [SOLVED]

Tags: c#, api, post, restsharp

I am trying to obtain a jwt token from Nowpayments API but have some issues, maybe someone from you guys have an idea to my problem.

```
private async void NowPaymentsAuth()
        {
            var options5 = new RestClientOptions("https://api.nowpayments.io")
            {
                MaxTimeout = -1,
            };
            var client5 = new RestClient(options5);
            var request5 = new RestRequest("/v1/auth", Method.Post);
            var body = @"{" + "\n" +
            @"    ""email"": ""test@gmail.com""," + "\n" +
            @"    ""password"": ""test123"" " + "\n" +
            @"}";
            request5.AddParameter("text/plain", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            RestResponse response5 = await client5.ExecuteAsync(request5);
            MessageBox.Show(response5.Content);
        }
```

This is an example response:

```
{
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjU4MjYyNTkxMTUiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDUyODgzODQsImV4cCI6MTYwNTI4ODY4NH0.bk8B5AjoTt8Qfm1zHJxutAtgaTGW-2j67waGQ2DUHUI"
}
```

My response:

> "{"status":false,"statusCode":400,"code":"INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMS","message":"email is required"}"

My email and my password is 100% right -> the POST request seems right to me

I expected an jwt Token as an answer and rechecked my Code and my email and password.
I would be very happy if someone in here has an idea. I tried debug some Lines of the Code to figure out the issue but with no success.

Comment: You may want to use a JSON library rather than constructing the JSON string yourself. Why do you use `text/plain` when you are really transmitting `application/json` MIME type?

Comment: Hey mate you are right! I just fixxed it.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer to your question. It will help others who will stuck with similar cases